Is there a safe way to store user data in the local storage of a WebView?
I've been thinking about creating a simple feature to help users to login.
The issue I'm trying to solve comes from the fact that when using a WebView inside an app, we can't really control the login duration, and having to type your username and password on a weekly basis can be frustrating.
I had this idea where I would inject a simple Javascript code snippet into the WebView, to capture the user input when he fills the login form, store those details locally, and then automatically fill the form for him.
Here is a simple working Javascript code snippet I prepared using AI for this purpose:
// Get references to both input fields
const emailInput = document.getElementById('CustomerEmail');
const passwordInput = document.getElementById('CustomerPassword');

// Define keys for local storage (one for each field)
const emailStorageKey = 'customerEmailContent';
const passwordStorageKey = 'customerPasswordContent';

// Event listeners for input
emailInput.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  localStorage.setItem(emailStorageKey, event.target.value); 
});

passwordInput.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  localStorage.setItem(passwordStorageKey, event.target.value); 
});

// Function to load from local storage and retry on failure
function loadFromLocalStorage() {
  const savedEmail = localStorage.getItem(emailStorageKey);
  const savedPassword = localStorage.getItem(passwordStorageKey);

  if (savedEmail) {
    emailInput.value = savedEmail;
  }
  if (savedPassword) {
    passwordInput.value = savedPassword;
  } else {
    // Fallback: Retry after a short delay
    setTimeout(loadFromLocalStorage, 500); // Retry after 500 milliseconds
  }
}

// Initial attempt to load on DOMContentLoaded
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loadFromLocalStorage);

// Additional attempt after a longer delay (e.g., if some scripts take time)
setTimeout(loadFromLocalStorage, 2000); // Retry after 2 seconds


Now my main concern is related to possible security concerns when doing something like this in a WebView.
On the web, there seems to be an obvious security flaw, but in a WebView inside an app, should I have the exact same concerns? Any extra concerns?
My thought is that you wouldn't be able to access the Javascript getting injected into the WebView, and since the data would be stored in the local storage it would only be accessible by the user.
Any extra details on how to make this work would be appreciated.
I've tried searching for more details on WebView security, but couldn't find anything specific to a use case like the one I'm working on.
Also tried ChatGPT but only got generic answers on this topic, probably due to the lack of material on such a specific use case.

The industry standard is to use refresh tokens which your backend must support. The token should be stored securely on the iOS device keychain. WKWebview is conceptually not different to a web browser. Storing password in WKWebview is a terrible idea and could be exploited in many ways.
